# Creating central repository in Git from existing local repository (in Windows)

Tags: git, repository

I've looked around StackOverflow and other places (including Git documentation) and just cannot get this to work.  Here's what i've done:

To setup central repository (on //SomeUNC);

```
git init --bare Central.git
```

This creates a //SomeUNC/Central.git folder.

Now, in local repository, i try:

```
git remote add Central //SomeUNC/Central.git (this is ok)
git push -all Central
```

This gives the error:

fatal: 'Central' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

I'm sure I'm missing something simple.  Thank for any help!

Comment: Are you able access `//SomeUNC/Central.git` from your local machine (using windows file browser)?

Comment: @Justinᚅᚔᚈᚄᚒᚔ, my apologies.  I have accepted your answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It sounds like your paths aren't valid. Delete the bare repository and try this from your local repository working folder:

```
git init --bare //UNC/Path/to/Central.git
git remote add Central //UNC/Path/to/Central.git
git push --all Central
```

Comment: @rht341: My pleasure. Please remember to accept correct answers on all of your questions by clicking the large checkmark next to the vote count.